# After insert data into pgsql With FireDAC, the data info changed

Tags: delphi, firedac

Develop tool: Delphi 10.1 Berlin

With FireDAC in Delphi: INSERT INTO ttb(x) VALUES(aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=333);

Before insert:
aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=333

However after insert with FireDAC, the string becomes:
aaa=111=222=333

**That is to say, the characters "&bbb" and "&ccc" were deleted while using FireDAC.**

Could you tell me how to fix it, thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code you use to call that statement (in order to see how you handle those strings) ?

Comment: FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO ttb VALUES(' + QuotedStr('aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=333') + ');');;
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
  FDQuery1.Close;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better get habit to always use parameters in queries
([Online documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Executing_Commands_(FireDAC)#Using_Parameters)), 
as it allows you to avoid such problems. 
In your case code should look like:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text:='insert into ttb (x) values(:TestData)';
FDQuery1.Params.ParamByName('TestData').AsString:='aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=333';
FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

In Addition to benefits mentioned in documentation, you would be safe from SQL injection and various other "nasty" things that might happen to your database if not using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for updates and inserts it is much cleaner to use FDConnection component itself.

Example:

```
FDConnection.ExecSQL(
  'insert into ttb (x) values(:TestData)',
  ['aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=333'],
  [ftString]);
```

No extra queries needed. Clean and simple!